# how to solve a problem of reading an element of a dictionary whatever the order of the couple constituting its key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm facing problems reading instances from a dictionary.

I defined a dict and add items to it in a certain order (title, author). But I am asked to check them in reverse form (author, title) to check their availability. To illustrate, I have a book instance:

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, title, author):
```

This is the library class which consists of a dictionary of books:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        #fill in here to define the books attribute/instance variable

        self.books = dict()
        self.book_inst = Book("", "") 

    def add_book(self, book_inst):
        if (book_inst.author, book_inst.title) not in self.books:
            # fill in here
            self.books.update({(book_inst.author, book_inst.title):{"checked_out": 0, "available": 1}})
        else:
            # fill in here
            self.books[(book_inst.author, book_inst.title)]["available"] += 1
```

This method checks the availability of books in the library and I do not have to change the defined order.

```
    def can_check_out(self, book_inst):
        book = (book_inst.author, book_inst.title)
        if book in self.books:
            # fill in here

            if(self.books[book]['available'] >= 1):
                    return True
```

So when I check as requested, I get a legitimate exception:

```
hatcher = Library("Hatcher Library")
hatcher.books[("Webster's Dictionary", "Merriam-Webster")]
```

Note: here author = "Merriam-Webster", Title = "Webster's Dictionary"
Here is the exception:

```
  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-68f3ca845b8e> in <module>()
      3 #hatcher.books[('Darrell Huff', 'How to Lie with Statistics')]
      4 hatcher.can_check_out(Book('Darrell Huff', 'How to Lie with Statistics'))
----> 5 hatcher.books[("Webster's Dictionary", "Merriam-Webster")]

KeyError: ("Webster's Dictionary", 'Merriam-Webster')
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you just reverse the tuple and then perform the lookup in your dict?

Comment: You should use self.books.get to check the condition. Otherwise it will always raise an exception.

Comment: `if self.books.get(book, {"available": -1})['available'] >= 1:` ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "overcome the problem" means? What did you expect to happen instead in the "Webster's Dictionary" example?

Comment: This line is a test in the  required format  `hatcher.books[("Webster's Dictionary", "Merriam-Webster")] ` , ( Title, Author). And I can not change that.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But what did you expect to happen as a result of executing this line, instead of a `KeyError`?

Comment: Books are created in format (title, author), but they are added in format (author, title) in a dict. Verification of book instances should be done in the format (title, author) which is the format in which they were created. This raises an exception because it is the reverse of the format in which books are created.

Comment: Yes @mkrieger1. The result should be something like this  `{'checked_out': 0, 'available': 1}`

Comment: But in the example, no book was added to the library instance. Why do you expect that for any book, the result should be "available: 1"?

Comment: I do no know, but is this possible to create a dictionnary where keys are tuples (where order no matter )?

Comment: Of course this is possible. But you need to actually *call* the `add_book` method which inserts something into the dictionary. It seems you do not call this method at all in the example, so obviously no book will be found when you try to check if it is available.

Comment: How to do that ? Try to give an example please !

Comment: Just like calling any method!? `hatcher.add_book(some_book)`, where `some_book` is an instance of the `Book` class. (I thought you wrote this code – I don’t quite understand why we have to explain to you how to use it)

Comment: Your question is legitimate. But the problem is this, there are parts of this code that I cannot change. And I can just change the lines after the comment `# fill here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using frozensets as your dictionary keys? Then the order won't matter.

```
books = {}
books.update({frozenset(('author', 'title')): {'available': 1}})
book1 = books.get(frozenset(('author', 'title')))
book2 = books.get(frozenset(('title', 'author')))

print(book1 == book2)
print(book1.get('available'))
```

Output:

```
True
1
```

Comment: Thank you @dominik Buty it seems that  frozenset indicates that a the instance has been frozen while I'm looking for something that will make it flexible (A, B) =(B, A) for example.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what a frozenset does! It's an unordered collection of items, so frozenset((A,B)) == frozenset((B,A))

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/frozenset

Comment: Thank you @dominik. I have replaced the concerned line as you said, but still getting the same exception.: `KeyError: ("Webster's Dictionary", 'Merriam-Webster')` which is the key reversed

Comment: The KeyError says you're trying to access the dictionary with a tuple:
`hatcher.books[("Webster's Dictionary", 'Merriam-Webster')]`


If your dictionary keys are frozensets, you need to access them with frozensets too:
`hatcher.books[frozenset(("Webster's Dictionary", 'Merriam-Webster'))]`